# Xamarin... How do you link a file in the Main (PCL?) project into the OS specific project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, app-config

I'm following this tutorial for setting up an app.config on a Xamarin app.

[The Tutorial](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73623/appsettings-reader-for-xamarin-and-xamarin-forms)

one of the last steps is:

**Add this PCL app.config file as a linked file on all your platform projects**. For android, make sure to set the build action to ‘AndroidAsset’, for UWP set the build action to ‘Content’
Access your setting:

I have no idea what they are taking about, how in Vs2017 do I add a file as a linked file to the sub-os projects?

I'm sure this is stupid simple, but I'm totally missing it. thanks.

Comment: when you add an existing file to a project, you should get a prompt to either copy/move/link the file

Comment: I never got prompted, but I found the drop down that let me choose. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I  figured it out

Right click on Project, add existing select teh file, on the add dialog the add button has a dropdown, change it to add link.

[image]